# ethereum local cluster with bootnodes

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

Geth 1.6.7. 
I have used this manual

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster

looks very simple

1. run bootnode

> ./bootnode -nodekeyhex
>   dc90f8f7324f1cc7ba52c4077721c939f98a628ed17e51266d01c9cd0294033a
>
> UDP listener up
>   self=enode://890b6b5367ef6072455fedbd7a24ebac239d442b18c5ab9d26f58a349dad35ee5783a0dd543e4f454fed22db9772efe28a3ed6f21e75674ef6203e47803da682@[::]:30301

run 2 geth`s on the local machine

> geth --bootnodes
>   enode://890b6b5367ef6072455fedbd7a24ebac239d442b18c5ab9d26f58a349dad35ee5783a0dd543e4f454fed22db9772efe28a3ed6f21e75674ef6203e47803da682@127.0.0.1:30301
>   --datadir "./node1" --port 30310 --rpcport 8110 --ipcdisable --networkid 1024 --cache=512 --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc console 2>> ./node1/geth1.log
>
> geth --bootnodes
>   enode://890b6b5367ef6072455fedbd7a24ebac239d442b18c5ab9d26f58a349dad35ee5783a0dd543e4f454fed22db9772efe28a3ed6f21e75674ef6203e47803da682@127.0.0.1:30301
>   --datadir "./node1" --port 30311 --rpcport 8111 --ipcdisable --networkid 1024 --cache=512 --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc console 2>> ./node1/geth1.log

checked peers via console

> admin.peers []

As you can see nodes do not see each other. What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the second instance to your admin node (i.e. your first instance). Run the command `admin.addPeer(enodeUrlOfFirstInstance)`.